# And-Or Usage | Exclusion or Inclusion of Listed Items

Tags: lists, legalese, and-or

During a debate the other night in the NM legislature there was a question as to whether the list in the paragraph pictured was **exclusionary** or **inclusionary** due to the use of "or" followed by an "and" followed by another "or." It's my current understanding that because of the contextual use of the words "relate to" that the list logically includes all variables regardless of the use of an *and* or an *or*. Is this correct or does this language exclude certain scenarios? I'm also not sure if this would be a better question for a legal forum.

I tried searching for an answer but I couldn't find an example that had similar structure/context. 
[image: this one]

Comment: Surely it means: << The application shall include **(1)** the details of the proposed innovative teaching project and specific goals of the project, particularly as those goals relate to teaching **(a)** English language learners, **(b)** minority students, **(c)** developmentally disabled or delayed students, and **(d)** students who have become defeated by or uninterested in school ... >> But why can't _they_ bullet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of "or" in the citation is not exclusionary.

> developmentally disabled *or* delayed

the "or" connects  developmentally to

> disabled

and

> delayed

so the meaning is:

> (teaching) *developmentally disabled* (students) and (teaching) *developmentally delayed* (students)

And

> become defeated by *or* uninterested in school

is actually:

> (students who) *become defeated by* (school) and (students who) *become uninterested* ( in school)